# Managing Entity Framework at Enterprise Projects (with hundred of tables)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, code-first

I am using Entity Framework at my work and faced some problems.

Usually I hear about creating tiny Edmx´s files containing tables related to some Domain ie.: Help Desk Edmx, HR Edmx, etc. Instead of load all tables in one big Edmx, what would be much simpler, but for performance considerations(at design and build time mainly), it isn´t feasible.

It took me to some troubles, first about the commom tables, ie.: Employees Tables, it is at all Edmx´s, conflicting when I use a Employee class reference and have a using to both namespaces, then I have to reference the Empoyee class by the full name MyCompany.HelpDesk.Employee.

It doesn´t look natural.

I find myself repeatedly adding the same tables at all EDMX´s, it´s a rework, and I spend some minutes adding a table to entity framework design since I have 2k tables at Add Table Dialog.

Maybe VS2012 could be a solution to load 2k Tables at the same Edmx file(since the designer could be splitted), but I don´t believe that, because it delay to compile too, not only to open the designer.

Another option could be the Code First, but it doesn´t have a decent tool to Reverse Engineer the database to classes, since it tries to load all the tables from database, tooking about 2 hours!

Comment: 2k tables? Are you trying to build ERP with EF?

Comment: Something like that. In my company we don´t have a ERP like SAP or AX

Answer (score 1):

There is generally no solution for your problem. EF supports some way to [share common entities across multiple CSDL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/11/25/working-with-large-models-in-entity-framework-part-2.aspx) files but it has a lot of disadvantages:

- It is not supported by designer (I didn't try if VS2012 designer support this) -> you are going to maintain EDMX files as XML
- It is supported only on CSDL level (classes) -> you still have single SSDL (tables) and MSL (mapping) and you must maintain them manaully
- Only unidirectional relationships to shared entities (shared entity can have navigation properties only to other shared entities).

VS2012 will allow you working with multiple diagrams in single EDMX but I really don't know how fast this will be with 2k tables.

IMHO 2k tables doesn't sound like use case for EF mapping features - especially not for features where you expect the code to be generated for you. Large scale development usually involves large scale coding or developing your own tools. Your current way (by mapping shared entities again) is the best approach with default EF tooling.

If you use T4 generator for POCO classes you can even modify T4 template to use always the same class for all EDMX files. POCO classes are mapped only by class names - namespace doesn't make any difference. This will require you to put some effort into T4 generator to make sure that shared classes are generated only once and correctly referenced from all your model specific classes.

Btw. how much time does it take to start your application and load all your mappings? Are you using pregenerated EF views?

Comment: I did a try, the first instance of context delays 1400ms and the first query(when load the metadata) 330000ms

Comment: That is what I expected - start of the application takes ages ... You can improve it by using [pregenerated EF views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx). This pregeneration is usually used as some pre-build / build action => your build will slow down significantly.

Comment: Using pre generated views took 1300ms/9300ms. I disabled Validation on Build on Edmx, and compile time descrease from 10 minutos to 5 seconds!

Comment: But turning validation off can introduce errors in your mapping. Anyway 9 seconds to execute query is still too much.

Comment: I dont edit the edmx, I just need to map from database and use this dll at my applications

Comment: It would be better to use specialized EDMX with only used tables for each application instead of trying to use some huge models.

Comment: The problem is to manage all them. I have some projects using 3 edmx´s, all 3 with some shared tables, and I need to put 3 connections strings at web.config